# Has "==" and "-eq" changed behavior since early releases of bash:?

Tags: bash

There is a script here
[set intel cpu freq](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/comment/1716807/how-to-change-frequency-on-linux-pub.txt)

that I have used in the past to lower the frequency of my INTEL cpu when it was overheating.  Usually only one step down is sufficient and keeps it out of "boost".  It has been several years since I had to do that but recently a cheap mining system I put together had a problem and when I ran that script it failed and I had to substitute "-eq" for "==" The script came from the intel developers department and I am positive it ran correctly for Ubuntu 14 or maybe 12. Forget what I was using back then.
When I run the below I get the branch where METHOD is 0 which works correctly but I had to put in -eq instead of ==

```
METHOD=0
..
        if [ $METHOD -eq 0 ]; then
--
userspace
Setting /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor to  userspace
Setting freq /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed to  2800000
```

Comment: One of the numbers is not an integer?

Comment: Copy and paste from the script from my home folder: ```METHOD=0 # 0=use setspeed, 1=use min max
```  I think it is a zero and not an o

Comment: If you use a single `[` you are using `test` and not the bash logical operator that requires the double `[[` (`[`/`test` is optimized as a bash builtin but should still exhibit the `test` behavior). And is the script are actually using `bash` or just `sh`?

Comment: I downloaded the script from the intel group and did the copy and paste cutting at the line of code that the script author said to and I saved it as chg_freq.sh and did a chmod +x to it.

Comment: Early releases of BASH?   BASH (1989) is older than Linux (1991) and well older than Ubuntu (2004). Anything from the last decade is not an *early* release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a single `[` you are using `test` and not the bash logical operator that requires the double `[[`.

In both `bash` and `sh` (which is `dash` in Ubuntu) `[`/`test` is optimized as a shell builtin but their behavior is not the same, in bash `==` is a strict equivalent of `=` but it is not so in dash.

And the shebang of the script you point to is `#! /bin/sh` so depending on platform it will be bash or dash.